# the attribute path is undefined for the annotation type RequestMapping

Tags: path, annotations, attributes, mapping

At compile time, I am getting the error

> the attribute path is undefined for the annotation type
>   RequestMapping

I have imported `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable`, but I am still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml check dependency version of spring-web. I solved it by changing the version dependency. Previously it was 4.1.4.RELEASE.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```